# Login restriction in django

Tags: python, django, login-required

This is a very basic question cause I´m new using django. I made a login form that works just fine with the users i have in the database. The problem is that if i enter, for example, "localhost:8000/Exi/index" it does go to the main 'Home' page, the problem, obviously, is that i want users to see this page only if they are logged in. I tried with the

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls):
        return login_required(super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view())

class Index (LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

But that doesn´t work for me. Maybe im not seeing something cause i looked around a couple of similar questions here and everyone seemed to have fix this in their projects.
This is my urls for this  page:

> url(r'^$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
>       url(r'^index$', views.Index.as_view(), name='index')

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For class-based views I encourage you to use [django-braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.0/access.html#loginrequiredmixin)'s `LoginRequiredMixin`

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin


class YourSecuredView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "yourtemplate.html"
```

Notice that `LoginRequiredMixin` has to be the left-most mixin.

Comment: Diego, 1°- que cagada que españa se quedo afuera tan pronto de la copa, 2°- Braces lo tengo que colocar en "Installed Apps" antes de invocarlo mediante las Views?. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: No, you don't need to add django_braces to INSTALLED_APPS, just install it with pip and import wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the documentation of Django: [The login-required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)

Example from the docs for simple views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

For class-based views, you can use the decorator in two different ways, as described in the docs: [Decorating class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views)

First way, in the url routing definition:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .views import VoteView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^about/', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="secret.html"))),
    (r'^vote/', permission_required('polls.can_vote')(VoteView.as_view())),
)
```

Second way, in the view itself:

```
class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I did this once: 
@login_required(login_url= 'login')
class Index (TemplateView):
    
    template_name = 'index.html'

and i see this error: 
'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

I don´t know if its because i´m using class based views...
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's site-wide login restrictions you need give https://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold#stronghold a try.

Comment: OK, i tried it and follow the installation and i still have the same problem, i write 'Localhost:8000/Exi/index' and i still have access to that page without login in. Any ideas?...i´m really stuck